# Find the derivative of $y^2 = x^3$ (without implicit differentiation)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is this a typo in the question? If $y$ can have more than one value to the same $x$ input, is it even a function? Should I calculate the derivative for $\sqrt{x^3}$ and for $-\sqrt{x^3}$?

Comment: For both, it can written as $\pm \sqrt{x^3}$. Now apply rule for differentiating polynomials.

Comment: Thank you, I didnt notice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No one is saying there are more than 1 value to the same input. Saying "find the derivative of $y^2=x^3$" is a sloppy way of writing things. One starts by assuming there is a function $y$ such that for all $x$ in its domain $I$, we have $y(x)^2=x^3$, and furthermore assuming that the function $y$ is differentiable. In this case, since the equality $y(x)^2=x^3$ holds for all $x\in I$, we can differentiate at any point of $I$ to get by the chain rule that
\begin{align}
2y(x)y'(x)&= 3x^2.
\end{align}
If $x\neq 0$, then $y(x)^2=x^3\neq 0$ implies that $y(x)\neq 0$, so we can divide the above equation to find that $y'(x)=\frac{3x^2}{2y(x)}$. Notice how the derivative actually depends on the function itself.

To really convince yourself, let's consider $y_1:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb{R}$ defined as $y_1(x)=\sqrt{x^3}$. Then, $y_1$ is a differentiable function and for all $x\in I=(0,\infty)$, we have $y_1(x)^2=x^3$. The derivative is calculated as
\begin{align}
y_1'(x)&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^3}}\cdot 3x^2=\frac{3x^2}{2y_1(x)},
\end{align}
which coincides with what we expected above.

Similarly, if you consider $y_2:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb{R}$ as $y_2(x)=-\sqrt{x^3}=-y_1(x)$. Then, we again have for all $x\in I=(0,\infty)$ that $y_2(x)^2=x^3$, and $y_2$ is differentiable, and
\begin{align}
y_2'(x)=-y_1'(x)=-\frac{3x^2}{2\sqrt{x^3}}=-\frac{3x^2}{2y_1(x)}=\frac{3x^2}{2y_2(x)},
\end{align}
again, as expected.

---

Just in case it isn't already clear, there are actually infinitely many functions $y:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb{R}$ satisfying the condition that for all $x\in (0,\infty)$, $y(x)^2=x^3$. For example,
\begin{align}
y(x)&=
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{x^3}&\text{if $x$ is rational}\\
-\sqrt{x^3}&\text{if $x$ is irrational}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
is one possibility. You can come up with infinitely many other crazy examples. So, the equation $y^2=x^3$ by itself doesn't tell you anything about the function. Having said this however, there are only two functions satisfying $y(x)^2=x^3$ which are **differentiable**, namely the $y_1,y_2$ above. And for these functions, we have a formula for their derivatives (in every case, it is just an application of the chain rule).